# Can Cypher return a increment chain of numbers?

Tags: cypher, increment

For example, can I have such a command that generate the increment of number?

```sql
MATCH (n) 
RETURN n, number_increment

node A   1
node B   2
node C   3
node D   4
```

I want to assign id to a group of nodes (not the `id(n)` one) and I need a chain of increasing number. Is this doable in Cypher or I need to use another language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want something like a row number. There isn't a direct way to do it in cypher, but there are a number of different solutions. One way is using the [`apoc.coll.zip`](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc.coll/apoc.coll.zip/) function and manipulating the result into collections,

```
MATCH (n) 
WITH collect(n) as nodes
WITH apoc.coll.zip(nodes, range(0, size(nodes))) as pairs
UNWIND pairs as pair 
RETURN pair[0] as n, pair[1] as rowNumber
```

(Be careful though, the above query selects all nodes in the store, so may take a while if you have a huge number of nodes)

Comment: we can change `WITH collect(n) as nodes` to `WITH collect(n.name) as nodes` to reduce the result length

Comment: Playing with this I get some weird results. Can you help? [Some weird results of apoc.coll.zip()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69736707/3416774)

Comment: Follow up question: [How to set node properties as increasing numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70799657/3416774)

Answer (score 1):

This will work.

```
MATCH(n)
WITH RANGE(1, COUNT(n)) AS indexes, COLLECT(n) AS nodes
FOREACH(i IN indexes | SET (nodes[i-1]).myID = i)
WITH nodes UNWIND nodes AS node
RETURN node
```

Comment: doesn't work to me. It return `V2` and no property is set. I cut the line `WITH nodes UNWIND nodes AS node` and just `RETURN nodes` and it returns `V1`. Weird