# Some weird results of apoc.coll.zip()

Tags: arrays, cypher, nested-lists, neo4j-apoc, unwind

I create 3 test nodes with name properties are "a", "b", "c", and use [`apoc.coll.zip()`](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc.coll/apoc.coll.zip/) to combine two lists together:

```sql
MATCH (n:test) 
WITH collect(n.name) as nodes 
WITH apoc.coll.zip(nodes, range(0, size(nodes))) as pairs 
RETURN pairs;

+--------------------------------+
| pairs                          |
+--------------------------------+
| [["a", 0], ["b", 1], ["c", 2]] |
+--------------------------------+
```

The result is expected. What is interesting is when I modify the query either by adding another column in the `RETURN` clause or by `UNWIND`ing the pair.

## 1. `RETURN pairs,n.name;`

```sql
MATCH (n:test)
WITH n, collect(n.name) as nodes
WITH n, apoc.coll.zip(nodes, range(0, size(nodes))) as pairs 
RETURN pairs,n.name;
+---------------------+
| pairs      | n.name |
+---------------------+
| [["a", 0]] | "a"    |
| [["b", 0]] | "b"    |
| [["c", 0]] | "c"    |
+---------------------+
```

I expect the result to be exactly the same with the query:

```sql
MATCH (n:test) 
WITH n, [["a", 0], ["b", 1], ["c", 2]] as nested 
RETURN nested, n.name;

+---------------------––––––––––––––––––--+
| pairs                          | n.name |
+---------------------––––––––––––––––––--+
| [["a", 0], ["b", 1], ["c", 2]] | "a"    |
| [["a", 0], ["b", 1], ["c", 2]] | "b"    |
| [["a", 0], ["b", 1], ["c", 2]] | "c"    |
+---------------------––––––––––––––––––--+
```

## 2. `UNWIND pairs as pair RETURN pairs`

```sql
MATCH (n:test)
WITH n, collect(n.name) as nodes
WITH n, apoc.coll.zip(nodes, range(0, size(nodes))) as pairs
UNWIND pairs as pair
RETURN pairs;

+------------+
| pairs      |
+------------+
| [["a", 0]] |
| [["b", 0]] |
| [["c", 0]] |
+------------+
```

I expect the result to be no different than having no `UNWIND` clause:

```
+--------------------------------+
| pairs                          |
+--------------------------------+
| [["a", 0], ["b", 1], ["c", 2]] |
+--------------------------------+
```

## 3. `UNWIND pairs as pair RETURN pair`

```sql
MATCH (n:test)
WITH n, collect(n.name) as nodes
WITH n, apoc.coll.zip(nodes, range(0, size(nodes))) as pairs
UNWIND pairs as pair
RETURN pair;
+----------+
| pair     |
+----------+
| ["a", 0] |
| ["b", 0] |
| ["c", 0] |
+----------+
```

I expect the result to be no different than simply `UNWIND` a nested list:

```sql
UNWIND [["a", 0], ["b", 1], ["c", 2]] as list 
RETURN list;

+----------+
| list     |
+----------+
| ["a", 0] |
| ["b", 1] |
| ["c", 2] |
+----------+
```

Do you know why these happen? They don't seem to be explained in [`RETURN`](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/return/) and [`UNWIND`](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/unwind/) documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all the 3 queries listed, the key point is at,

```
...
WITH n, collect(n.name) as nodes
...
```

`collect` is an [aggregating function](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/aggregating/#functions-collect) and it can be grouped. Specifying 'n' in the `WITH` clause causes it to do "group by" similar to SQL grouping. Therefore if you have 3 nodes, you get 3 results.

You can debug by `RETURN`ing after the `WITH` to see the result at each step,
like so,

```
MATCH (n:test)
WITH n, collect(n.name) as nodes
RETURN n, nodes
```

Comment: hmm. So the way to fix this is to have a dedicated `WITH` clause for `n`? Once there is a `WITH` clause for a variable, will it be brought forward, even when other `WITH` clauses don't have it?

Comment: one simplistic way to look at it is to imagine each 'WITH` clause as a stopping point in the execution where the intermediate results are collected and then sent as input to the next part of the cypher statement

Comment: yes, but when the next part has another `WITH` clause and we don't remind the variable again,, then would it be forgotten again?

Comment: yes thats right

Comment: but if so, then how can the fix work? `n` will be forgotten right after `WITH collect(n.name) as nodes`

Comment: yes it will be forgotten, you have to carry over 'n' if you want to refer to it later. or pull out the properties that you need from `n`  and include with the `WITH` clause