# How to set node properties as incrementing numbers?

Tags: neo4j, set, cypher, increment

I want to assign id to a group of nodes (not the `id()` one). From this answer I can [return the increment of number along with the nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69720554/3416774):

```sql
MATCH (n) where n.gid="Tt" 
WITH collect(n) as nodes
WITH apoc.coll.zip(nodes, range(0, size(nodes))) as pairs
UNWIND pairs as pair 
RETURN pair[0].gid as gid, pair[1] as rowNumber

╒═════╤═══════════╕
│"gid"│"rowNumber"│
╞═════╪═══════════╡
│"Tt" │0          │
├─────┼───────────┤
│"Tt" │1          │
├─────┼───────────┤
│"Tt" │2          │
├─────┼───────────┤
│"Tt" │3          │
├─────┼───────────┤
```

However if I change the last line to

```sql
SET pair[0].id=pair[1]
```

then I got this error:

```
Invalid input '[': expected ":" (line 5, column 9 (offset: 145))
"set pair[0].id=pair[1]"
         ^
```

Is there a way to set the ids of the nodes to be incrementing numbers? Surely Cypher understands `pair[0]` alone as nodes; and if it's in the `RETURN` clause then `pair[0].id` still works. Why does this syntax not work in `SET`?

<sub>Follow up question: [How to set node properties as incrementing numbers, but resetting the increment when the value of a different property changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70803132/3416774)</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, wrapping the `pair[0]` in `()` to tell Neo4j that it's a node:

```
MATCH (n) where n.gid="Tt" 
WITH collect(n) as nodes
WITH apoc.coll.zip(nodes, range(0, size(nodes))) as pairs
UNWIND pairs as pair 
SET (pair[0]).id = pair[1]
```

Comment: Do you know what kind of syntax is this? Surely Cypher understands `pair[0]` alone as nodes; and if it's in the `RETURN` clause then `pair[0].id` still works. Why does this syntax not work in `SET`?

Comment: [How to set node properties as incrementing numbers, but resetting the increment when the value of a different property changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70803132/3416774)

Comment: I cannot tell you WHY SET does not take pair[0]  .  My 2cts? SET is an operation that modiefies data, so probably requirements are more strict than just RETURNing data.